# Where is "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform" coming from?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service-reference

I've added a service reference in Visual Studio 2022 Community (C#), and I'm using the service reference's methods below. This is a console application.

```
1 ServRef1.Service1Client client1 = new ServRef1.Service1Client();
2 ServRef1.HTDesigner hd = await client1.GetHTDesignerAsync();
```

Line 2 is throwing the error I copied into the title here about Dynamic code generation not being supported. My question is:

- Is this being generated by the service I'm referencing, or is it something I'm doing wrong?

I'm relatively new to Visual Studio settings, and I'm wondering if some compiling option I've selected has done this. I remember there was an option to pre-compile code, so maybe that's what's causing it? I can't seem to find where that is to turn it off, however.

On the other hand, I'm not sure the service reference code is great. Could that be causing the issue?

I'm using .NET 8.0.

As far as a minimal, reproducible example, I'm not sure I can do that because I'd have to provide information about the service reference, which is private. However, I can say that the lines I show here are literally the first two lines of the program, it has nothing else going on. I created a console application, added the service reference, created these two lines based on documentation, then ran into the bug.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of your project is?  And version.  Can you provide   [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I edited the question with more details. As I saw in there, I'm not sure I can produce a minimal viable example. I'm hoping someone can help me at least determine if my code / VS settings are likely to be causing this issue, or if it's the service reference  code. I'm not sure where I'm doing any dynamic code generation, which is confusing.

Comment: This error might indicate that your application is set to compile as [Native AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/), and that using a Service Reference is not compatible with that mode of compiling.

Comment: What type of service is this? HTTP? SOAP? gRPC?

Comment: @PeterB that appears to have done it! I found that setting and unchecked it, and now it's running without that error. Thanks!

Comment: @julealgon I'm working with a dll web service that a partner provided me, I've never done that before.

Comment: Hi, @YoungZaphod glad to know your problem has been solved! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.  Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application was set to compile as Native AOT, which apparently is not compatible with using a Service Reference because the Service Reference generates dynamic code.